# How do I create a Firestore query for documents created after a timestamp in the new modular sdk?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am rather new to Firestore, not to mention the new modular sdk, and I was wondering if anyone knows why this query returns a document with a createdAt timestamp that was before the timestamp that I provided? I only want documents that were created after the timestamp I provide.

```
const timeRef = useRef(Date.now());

const notificationQuery = query(
   collection(clientFirestore, `users/${uid}/notification_history`),
   orderBy("createdAt"),
   where("createdAt", ">=", timeRef.current),
   limit(1)
 );
```

I also tried this:

```
const notificationQuery = query(
   collection(clientFirestore, `users/${uid}/notification_history`),
   orderBy("createdAt"),
   startAfter(timeRef.current),
   limit(1)
);
```

Am I misusing the date or is the query wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems illogical: `useRef(Date.now())`. `Date.now()` gives you a number, not a path that you can pass to `useRef`.

Are you looking for [`Timestamp.now()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp.md#timestampnow)?

```
where("createdAt", ">=", Timestamp.now()),
```

Comment: Oh my lord, thank you so much. Not only did you reply within just minutes, but it indeed was exactly what I was looking for.

I don't know why I thought Date.now() made even the slightest bit of sense. I had actually looked into serverTimestamp, and I imported it like this:

import { serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

But I soon learned that it can only be used with update() and set(), since it is sort of a placeholder value that gets interpreted on the DB end, if I understood it correctly. 

I wish I could upvote your response 10 times over, you are an absolute lifesaver!